# Using overlapped IO for console input?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, io, overlapped-io

I'm attempting to use overlapped IO to read input from the console by opening CONIN$ with the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED flag.  However, ReadFile blocks when I use it, even with an OVERLAPPED parameter.

I've read some posts reporting that this is a Windows 7 bug.  I am using 7 so that could be possible.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
// Create a console window
AllocConsole();
AttachConsole(GetProcessId(GetModuleHandle(NULL)));

HANDLE overlappedConsoleIn = CreateFile(L"CONIN$",
                              GENERIC_READ,
                              FILE_SHARE_READ,
                              NULL,
                              OPEN_EXISTING,
                              FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
                              NULL);

// Set up the console to work with stdio
FILE *consoleOut = _fdopen(_open_osfhandle((long)GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), _O_TEXT), "w");
FILE *consoleIn = _fdopen(_open_osfhandle((long)overlappedConsoleIn, _O_TEXT), "r");

*stdout = *consoleOut;
*stdin = *consoleIn;

setvbuf(consoleOut, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(consoleIn, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

std::ios::sync_with_stdio();

// Create a completion event
HANDLE inputEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, true, false, NULL);

BYTE inputBuffer[128];

OVERLAPPED overlappedData;
overlappedData.Offset = 0;
overlappedData.OffsetHigh = 0;
overlappedData.hEvent = inputEvent;

DWORD numBytesRead = 0;

// Asynchronously read from console
ReadFile(overlappedConsoleIn, inputBuffer, 128, &numBytesRead, &overlappedData);

while(true)
{
    if(WaitForSingleObject(inputEvent, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        std::cout << "input has been received" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "doing something" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Does it work on other versions of Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you open `CONIN$` or `CONOUT$` the parameter `dwFlagsAndAttributes` is ignored (in the documentation of the [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is a complete description about how to open the console).  If you like to read the console asynchronously, you can pass the handle returned by `CreateFile` directly to the `WaitForSingleObject` function and if any Console event is pending this handle would be signaled, with the function [ReadConsoleInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684961%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) do you read the pending events.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686971%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is the complete documentation of how to use the console in windows.

Comment: This answer does not seem to make any sense. Passing a handle to WaitForSingleObject() does not allow asynchronous IO since that call obviously blocks.

Comment: @Kyberias: Not if you pass a timeout of zero.  Then the return value tells you whether the input queue is empty or not.