# nonblocking read from stdin

Tags: c, windows, console, nonblocking

I expect `ReadConsoleW()` to return after reading a specific number of bytes.
But it doesn't return.

How can I make `ReadConsoleW()` return as soon as it finished reading the number of bytes specified?

The code I tried is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>


int main()
{
    //something is being written to stdin.
    Sleep(2000);
    int b;
    int r;
    //read 3 wide character
    ReadConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &b, 3*sizeof(TCHAR), (LPDWORD)&r, NULL);
    //problem: no returns until enter pressed
    putc(b,stdout);
    while(1)
    {};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SetConsoleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to turn off `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` flag. No line editing will be available, but it won't wait until the Enter is pressed.

Note that you can't read three `WCHAR`s into an `int`.

Comment: but still it will wait for at least _one_ character in the buffer... i.e. it is still blocking read.

Comment: `PeekConsoleInput` is non-blocking, but you have to use `ReadConsoleInput` to consume the input (or check input event types to be sure that `ReadConsoleChars` won't block). (And whenever you want to wait for console events with timeout, just `WaitForSingleObject` on console handle).

Answer (score -2):

Consider also asynchronous I/O in Windows using ReadFile/WriteFile.
See [MSDN on asynchronous I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It is a little more complicated, but you do have what you want.

Comment: It [does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551644/using-overlapped-io-for-console-input) for console handles.