# C++ How to wait for keyboard input for a limited time

Tags: c++, keyboard, ncurses

I want my console application to stop and wait for the user to press a key. If there is no keyboard input after a limited time, let us say 2 seconds, execution should resume.

I know that no solution will be portable across all implementations, but are there at least simple solutions?

Some posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257544/c-wait-for-user-input) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449324/how-to-simulate-press-any-key-to-continue) deal with similar issues, but they don’t seem to offer an answer to that specific problem.

If I could use ncurses (which I can't), I would do something like this using the `getch()` and `timeout()` functions:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main()
{
    initscr();          // Start curses mode
    cbreak();           // Turn off line buffering
    timeout(2000);      // Wait 2000 ms for user input
    while (true) {
        addstr("You have 2 sec. to press 'q', otherwise ...\n");
        refresh();
        int inKey = getch();
        if (inKey == 'q') break;
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a timer in C++ to force input within a given time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944972/how-to-use-a-timer-in-c-to-force-input-within-a-given-time)

Comment: The solution there seems a bit complicated and, more importantly, other  people are suggesting this may not work. I though about using a combinaison of `std::thread` and `std::cin` to capture input and calculate time simultaneously, but I am not sure how this could work.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be to use low-level read() (assuming you are on Posix) coupled together with timeout signal. Since read() will exit with EINTR after signal processing, you'd know you reached the timeout.

Comment: OK, thanks, I will look into that. This means that this solution would at least work on POSIX compliant systems.

Comment: Low-level read plus poll() or select() on STDIN handle, with a timeout argument other than infinity?

Comment: @cardiffspaceman, polls/selects usually do not work on stdin, as it considered to be 'immediately available' and poll always returns that the descriptior can be read.

Comment: @SergeyA In my test it worked. It's what I've used in a few casual programs, because I'm used to using poll() to detect input in production code with slightly different I/O such as sockets and character drivers. The OP's immediate need is of course well handled by your answer.

Comment: @cardiffspaceman, sockets and character drivers are not files, so that is different. Having said that, I fully trust you that on your system you could poll on stdin