# how to stop a statement by setting time

Tags: turbo-c++

When 'cin' statement works we have no other choice but to input a value to it and proceed to the next  statement.

I want the program to be set in such a way that the cin statement functions only for 3 seconds and after that the next statement must work regardless of whether  value is given  into it or not.

Comment: What did you tried? Can you show some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a timer in C++ to force input within a given time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944972/how-to-use-a-timer-in-c-to-force-input-within-a-given-time)