# How to implement countdown Timers in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code where the user has to answer the question in 10 seconds or else he will lose, I know that I'm supposed to use threads but the problem is, I don't know how to do the timer, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: why are you supposed to use "threads"?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053175/is-it-possible-to-set-timeout-for-stdcin

Comment: you can simply use "clock()" function as explained in this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220477/how-to-use-clock-in-c]

Comment: here is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944972/how-to-use-a-timer-in-c-to-force-input-within-a-given-time

Comment: @Mourad thanks, it really helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need threads.

Assuming time is in ms:

```
updateLoop(){
    timeLeft = startingTime + 10.000 - now;
    if (timeLeft <= 0) {
        lose=true;
    }
    render();
}
```

EDIT: I probably misunderstood the question a bit. This seems to cover your question, as in @Mourad's comment: 
[How to use a timer in C++ to force input within a given time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944972/how-to-use-a-timer-in-c-to-force-input-within-a-given-time)